# Illustrator Script to select all groups with named X

Tags: json, adobe-illustrator

I have a layer "design" with several groups named "orderno" in there.

I want a script that would only select those.

I tried this code but I fail at selecting more than 1 group "orderno"

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;  
var layers = docRef.layers;  
var myLayer = layers["design"]; //this defines the layer that you want to get the selection from  
var myGroup = myLayer.groupItems["orderno"];

docRef.selection = null; //ensure there is nothing in the document selected already. this way you only get the selection you want.  
for(var a=0;a<myGroup.pageItems.length;a++){ //here we are looping through each pageItem of myLayer.  
     var currentItem = myGroup.pageItems[a];  
     currentItem.selected = true;  
}
```

I think I'm missing something at the 'currentItem' line...

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test the name of each group as you loop through them:

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;  
var layers = docRef.layers;  
var myLayer = layers["design"]; //this defines the layer that you want to get the selection from  

docRef.selection = null; //ensure there is nothing in the document selected already. this way you only get the selection you want.  
for(var a=0;a<docRef.groupItems.length;a++){
     if (docRef.groupItems[a].name == "orderno"){
     docRef.groupItems[a].selected = true;  
    }
}
```